# How to escape double pound sign '##' in python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have a password, which when decrypted in the code has double pound signs, ##. This chokes python as it seems to believe this is a comment. I've tried using the re.escape() function but that doesn't escape the double ##.

Is there any way to get python to treat the whole string as simply a string and nothing more?

I'm connecting to a rest URL to pull some data. It requires authentication.

`get_all_users_from_service_policy(ranger_host, get_connection_info('RANGER_API')[0], get_connection_info('RANGER_API')[1], cluster_name.cluster_name + '_' + service.service_name)`

get_connection_info is just a function that returns a username and encrypted password from a config file. And it does return the password properly, password## , for example.

The get_all_users_from_service_policy is doing this:

```
def get_all_users_from_service_policy(ranger_host, ranger_admin_user, ranger_admin_password, ranger_service, api_version="v2",
                                      ranger_port=6182):
    api_url = "https://{}:{}@{}:{}/service/public/{}/api/service/{}/policy".format(ranger_admin_user,
                                                                                   ranger_admin_password, ranger_host,
                                                                                   ranger_port, api_version,
                                                                                   ranger_service)
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    result = requests.get(api_url, auth=(ranger_admin_user, ranger_admin_password), verify=False)
    result = json.loads(result.content)
```

Comment: `#` in a string is never viewed as starting a comment. Could you share some code showing exactly what your problem is?

Comment: `x='##fart'  print(x)` works just fine

Comment: Added code as requested.

Comment: having `#` in a string doesn't cause issues, something else is up

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a url encoding issue. I solved it by doing..

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote(ranger_admin_password)
```